# How to upgrade codeplex solution with reference to TFS2012 library?

Tags: codeplex, svnbridge

I have downloaded the source code for https://svnbridge.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

I use the SVNBridge client version. It giving error when I try to perform check-out on a file as:

> There is an error in XML document (0,0).

I guess I need to update the TFS references in the project because I am using TFS 2012. So I open this solution in VS2010. I see that there is a reference for 'Codepelx.TFSLibrary'. I think this is not compatible with TSF2012, so I need a reference that is for TFS2012. Any idea where I can find this? Am I on right path to make the application work with TFS2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/discussions/400625

I have managed to make SvnBridge v6.2 work with TFS 2012 by refering to above article with minor changes as described below...

1. Download the code from CodePlex.
2. Unzip it to a folder.
3. There will be a batch file that builds all projects. Run that (double click).
4. Copy folder SvnBridgeVialis to your IIS server and follow below instructions.
5. I have followed above article (pasting text below). Only thing I have done differently is that:-
   Created the SVNBridge website application under the Sites at port 8081 and not under the Default Web Site.
6. > IIS Application Pool
   >
   > Create a custom AppPool, I called mine SvnBridge
   >
   > Set the AppPool Setting like so:  .
   >
   > Net Framework Version = v4.0
   >
   > Manged Pipline Mode = Integrated
   >
   > Enabled 32-Bit Applications = False
   >
   > Worker Processes = 2
   >
   > Identity = Network Service
   >
   > WebSite
   >
   > I setup the Bridge under the Default WebSite.
   >
   > Set SVNBridge as an application, not a virtual directory
   >
   > Set the Application Pool to the custom one created above
   >
   > Set the Physical Path Credentials to a TFS Trusted Windows Account for
   >   TFS.  When you set the physical path, there is a test button that will
   >   tell you its good
   >
   > Goto Authentication button  Set the following:
   >
   > Anonymous Authentication - Disabled
   >
   > ASP.NET Impersonation - Disabled
   >
   > Basic Authentication - Enabled
   >
   > Digest Authentication - Disabled
   >
   > Forms Authentication - Disabled
   >
   > Windows Authenticaiton - Disabled
   >
   > now Click on Basic Authentication and click Edit  Set the Default
   >   Domain to your NT Domain name  Ensure that Realm is blank
   >
   > Web.Config
   >
   > Set LogPath to a trusted Path
   >
   > Set the DomainIncludesProjectName to False
   >
   > Set the TFS URL to the new TFS Collection Name  something like: 
   >   http://myServerName.acme.com:8080/tfs/SuperCollection
   >
   > Set the System.web to this, you can change debug to false after you
   >   confirm it works:
   >
   > Set the System.net to this:

After doing this I tested it. Problem is that when I checkout any folder/file, then choose the checkout-directory as: C:\test on my local PC. The code from the TFS 2012 along with the checked-out files has been copied to the above folder on the PC where I am performing the check-out. I could not get the code which is being checked-out to go and sit into the TFS 2012.

Since I could not get the SVNBridge to do the migration of code from SVN into the TFS, I have used another tool (free) **SVN2TFS**:- http://svn2tfs.codeplex.com/

Now I have successfully migrated code from SVN along with revision history and folder structure into TFS2010.

I think now next step is to migrate from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 which should not be a difficult task.